# Unable to invoke Apex Class in lightning component for non-admin user

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a quick action which invoke a lighting component.It calls the apex class from there based on user input.The issue is button is working for all the user , but once the user input Yes/No, it closes without any action for non-admin users.It works perfectly if the user is admin.Can anybody help me to understand the issue?

---

JS Controller

```
    ({

    yesResponse : function(component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.recallApproval");

        action.setParams({
          "currId": component.get("v.recordId"),
        });
        //alert(action);
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log('state '+state);
            if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){

               var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success!",
                    "message": "Success",
                    "type": "success"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }else{
              console.error("fail:" + response.getError()[0].message); 
            }
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
          });
          $A.enqueueAction(action);



    },

    noResponse : function(component, event, helper) {

        alert('Deactivation Cancelled');
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

---

apex class
-----------------------------------------------------`

```
global class approvalRecall
{   @AuraEnabled
    webservice static void recallApproval(id currId)  


    {   system.debug('approvalRecall class invoked..');
        List <Costing_Sheet_Item__c> relProd=[Select id,Costing_Sheet__c,Name from Costing_Sheet_Item__c where Costing_Sheet__c=:currId];
        List <Costing_Sheet__c> records=[Select id,Active__c,Approval_Status__c from Costing_Sheet__c where id=:currId];

     for(Costing_Sheet__c sp : records){
         //system.debug('relProd= '+relProd);
         sp.Active__c=False;
         sp.Approval_Status__c='Deactivated';

         system.debug('Approval.isLocked(sp.id)= '+Approval.isLocked(sp.id));
         if(Approval.isLocked(sp.id)){

             Approval.unlock(sp.id);

         }
     }
     update records;
     delete relProd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the browser's Developer Console (F12) to see if you had an error? It sounds like you have a permissions issue. Make sure the users can see all the objects and fields used by the class, and that the class itself is enabled for the profiles (found by clicking Security next to the class name in Setup).

Comment: Yes the class is available for the profiles.It turned out to be the issue with the sharing .When I changed "global  class approvalRecall" to "global  without sharing class approvalRecall", It worked.Thanks for the help.